# Exists in nested collection cannot find without ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collections

Hey guys another rails issue,

Currently have a collection that is line items for an invoicing system. I want to increment the count of the line items if I add in an item that already exists. At the moment I'm using an exists? query on the collection but it seems to return regardless of the key.

The foreign key I'm using is item_id, so I try to do `invoice_items.exists?(:item_id => item.id)`

This wasn't returning, so I changed it to `invoice_items.find(:conditions => ["item_id == ?", item.id)` and I get a return that I cannot search without invoiceItem ID.

Ideas?

Comment: What exactly are your two queries (the `exists?` and the `find?`) returning? It would also be helpful to see the relationship between `invoice_items` and `items` or whatever the foreign key `item_id` is actually referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
conditions => ["item_id == ?", item.id
```

should be

```
conditions => ["item_id = ?", item.id]
```

So your query look like this

```
invoice_items.find(:all).conditions => ["item_id = ?", item.id]
```

Answer (score -1):

you should just need to do either

```
invoice_items.all(:conditions => ["item_id == ?", item.id])
```

OR

```
invoice_items.first(:conditions => ["item_id == ?", item.id])
```

and you can use the syntax

```
invoice_items.all(:conditions => {:item_id => item.id})
```

if you are going to use the `model.find` command the first parameter needs to be `:all`, `:first`, `:last` or the primary key you are searching for.  that is why I generally prefer to use `Model.find` only if I am searching for an id, otherwise I use `Model.first`, `Model.last`, `Model.all`.  That way you know what you are going to get.